# CMake error "include could not find load file: FetchContent"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, cmake-modules, cmake-format

I am getting the following error while executing the `cmake` command on Ubuntu. CMake version - 3.10.2.

```
 mapp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/LocatePro$ cmake .
 -- Enable testing: ON
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (include):
  include could not find load file:

   FetchContent


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (FetchContent_Declare):
   Unknown CMake command "FetchContent_Declare".

 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/home/mapp/Desktop/LocatePro/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
 mapp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/LocatePro$
```

Following is the `CMakeLists.txt` content from line no. 31:

```
# we will use the network to fetch Google Test sources
# make it possible to disable unit tests when not on network
option(ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS "Enable unit tests" ON)
message(STATUS "Enable testing: ${ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS}")

if(ENABLE_UNIT_TESTS)
# the following code to fetch googletest
# is inspired by and adapted after:
#   - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
googletest
GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
GIT_TAG        release-1.8.0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(googletest)

if(NOT googletest_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(googletest)

    # Prevent GoogleTest from overriding our compiler/linker options
    # when building with Visual Studio
    set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    # Prevent GoogleTest from using PThreads
    set(gtest_disable_pthreads ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

    # adds the targers: gtest, gtest_main, gmock, gmock_main
    add_subdirectory(
      ${googletest_SOURCE_DIR}
      ${googletest_BINARY_DIR}
      )

    # Silence std::tr1 warning on MSVC
    if(MSVC)
      foreach(_tgt gtest gtest_main gmock gmock_main)
        target_compile_definitions(${_tgt}
          PRIVATE
            "_SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING"
          )
      endforeach()
    endif()
  endif()

 add_executable(LocatPro_Test "")

 target_sources(LocatPro_Test
    PRIVATE
    LocatProTest/LocatProTest.cpp
   )

  target_link_libraries(LocatPro_Test
     PRIVATE
     gtest_main
   )

  enable_testing()

  add_test(
     NAME google_test
     COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:LocatPro_Test>
     )
endif()
```

I am new to and today only I started working on CMake.
Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong and/or missing anything in CMake.

`include(FetchContent)` is supporting in CMAke version - 3.10.2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Module [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html) has appeared only in CMake 3.11.

(You may try to select previos CMake versions on the above link and find that the module is absent in that versions).